# Merging r dataset columns by copying rows

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset with 7 columns. One of the columns shows course cluster numbers (1-9, can have multiple numbers, like 1,4,5,6), and there are 3 columns (AH, SS, QS) that have logical value depending on the cluster number: if there is a number in 1-3 then the 1st column is True and so on. Here is the structure:

```
'data.frame':   213 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Major       : chr  "BUS" "BUS" "BUS" "BUS" ...
 $ CourseNumber: chr  "101" "105" "109" "110" ...
 $ Title       : chr  "Introduction to Business" "Foundations of Management" "Business Math" "Applied Statistics" ...
 $ Number      : chr  "4, 5" "5" "7, 8, 9" "7, 8, 9" ...
 $ AH          : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
 $ SS          : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ QS          : logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
```

I want to merge the last 3 columns into 1 column like this: if, for example, the values for AH, SS, QS are T, T, F,  the row will be copied into 2, where in one row the data will be AH, in the second row - SS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pivot your data, so that the column names (AH, SS, QS) appear in one column and the logical values in another column, and then you filter this dataset for rows that have the value TRUE in the new logical column. This can be done by using `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package:

```
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)  

  data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = AH:QS, # columns that will be pivotted 
                 names_to = "Variable", # Column name of the 'variable' column
                 values_to = "LogVal") %>% # column name of the logical value column
    filter(LogVal) %>% # filter only rows that contain a TRUE
    select(-LogVal) # remove the logical column
```